# simulate POST on link/button click event

Tags: jquery, rest, post, click, hyperlink

Have a list of editable items relative to a given user that I would like to be non-GET initiated; i.e. when clicking the edit button for a given entry, I would like that to initiate a `POST` to the target edit form screen.

How can I achieve this short of wrapping every edit button in the list in `<form>...</form>`?

Currently I have a jQuery location.href kicking the user to target edit screen; however, with GET the user could enter any id they like by simply entering a URI of their choosing.

```
$('.game-edit').click -> 
  location.href = '/admin/linescore/edit/' + getID($(this))
```

Can I click event POST a la `location.href`?

Ideas appreciated, thanks

Comment: What does this mean?  _"Can I click event POST a la location.href"_

Comment: Setting the browser location executes a GET. Why not use Ajax instead?

Comment: You can call `$("form").submit()` in the click handler, is that what you want?

Comment: @Barmar, there's a list of editable items, each with edit/delete buttons; clicking an edit button kicks the user to the target edit form screen

Comment: @Diodeus yes, I could probably ajax inject the response into target div container

Comment: @Madbreaks good question, jetlag'd presently.  Basically I'd like to initiate a POST event via a link/button click, much like a form post but without wrapping every item edit button in list in a form

Comment: What's the problem with the user being able to entering a URI of their choosing? Anything that comes from the browser can be simulated by the user.

Comment: @Barmar POST'ing blocks the curious from trying to modify content they don't have rights to.

Comment: No it doesn't, it just makes it a little harder.

Comment: @Barmar by curious, I mean the idle/bored user; not someone who will take the time to try to get around the POST requirement.

Comment: You also referred to "rights". If they don't have the rights to something, it shouldn't be done at the client end.

Comment: @Barmar it should be done at both ends

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
$('#formID').action = $(this).href
$('#formID').submit();
})
```

Comment: right, but this is not a form, it's a list of editable items whose targets are form screens

Comment: As you requested you want to post those links. The #formID will be a hidden form you may modify the code above to populate data in this form's input or hidden input then post them to the target.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't have jQuery do the POST for you?  Given:

```
<a class="edit" href="...">Click Me</a>
```

...then:

```
$('a.edit').click(function(){
    var postUrl = $(this).attr('href');  // href attribute of clicked link
    $.post(.....); 
});
```

**EDIT** - Updated for clarity's sake

Cheers

Comment: +1, interesting, what does the "$.post" use for its target, the link's href?

Comment: hmmm, this works, but I need to inject the response into some DOM container, which I don't feel like doing in this case. Is there a way to "$.post" and go to the target vs. asynchronously getting a response?

Comment: Yes, use a form.  You could build it dynamically in the click handler if you wish.  Then just set its POST action to the link's href and submit it.

Comment: meh, not what I wanted to hear ;-), but if that is the only way, so be it, will have to form wrap the edit buttons or dynamically build on click as you suggest. None of this is the straight forward redirect style approach I was looking for...might have to shift gears and ajax inject the response

Answer (score 0):

Ok, good answers here, but not really what I was looking for in terms of ease of implementation (yes, just ajax, but don't feel like dealing with injecting the form content response into DOM container and then handling the injected form's ajax event with jq "live" and any script loading issues).

What does work is simple: create an empty form block:

```
<form id="game-list" action="" method="post"></form>
```

then, given an edit button:

```
<input id="edit-@x.id" type="button" value="edit" class="game-edit" />
```

on click event, populate the form's action and submit:

```
$('.game-edit').click ->
  $('#game-list').attr('action', '/admin/linescore/edit/' + getID($(this)))
  gamesForm.submit()
```

That's a lot more direct than what I thought I needed to do, which was wrap every single edit button in a form wrapper. Of course, 6 hour timezone jetlag'd, am not thinking clearly, great time to be working ;-)